# who was the last to modify a pod in a namespace

Tags: command, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

is there a way to pull out the username who was the last one that updated a pod in a namespace?
I have already tried the below command but non of them get me the user name

```
helm get values *myservice*


kubectl get pod *mypod*
```

Comment: kubernetes doesn't have the concept built in of user management

Comment: Thanks Daniel. actually, my manager asked me to create a pipeline which automatically destroy the test & Dev env's which have not been logged in for  more that 2 weeks. so you think there is no way to pull out the user. right?

Answer (score 1):

If you are the cluster-admin, then you can check the kubernetes **audit logs** and determine the activities done in any particular namespace.

You can find more about auditing [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug/debug-cluster/audit/).